# White noise at non integer intervals, bug or my mistake?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, time-series, signal-processing

I'm intending to add white noise to a simple periodic signal

```
   p = TransformedProcess[
         Cos[t/8] + noise[t],
         noise \[Distributed] WhiteNoiseProcess[],
         t];
```

Adding it at integer intervals is fine

```
   data = RandomFunction[p, {0, 10}]
```

yields a TemporalData value as expected

But

```
   data = RandomFunction[p, {0, 10, 0.1}]
```

causes an error

"The specification WhiteNoiseProcess[NormalDistribution[0,1]] is not a random process recognized by the system"

Am I at fault or is it a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is to do with `RandomFunction`

For continuous-time processes with jumps, such as `WhiteNoiseProcess[]` the step dt is random and given by the process itself.

e.g this works

```
RandomFunction[WhiteNoiseProcess[1/3], {0, 50}]
```

This doesn't

```
RandomFunction[WhiteNoiseProcess[1/3], {0, 50,0.1}]
```

For continuous-time processes without jumps, such as `WienerProcess` an explicit dt needs to be given.

e.g this works

```
RandomFunction[WienerProcess[], {0, 50, 0.1}]
```

this doesn't

```
RandomFunction[WienerProcess[], {0, 50}]
```

You can't mix the two.

Comment: thanks, that with https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesRescale.html will meet my needs. Just makes me ponder about the real nature of white noise. Is there a better solution to modelling acoustic noise than white noise? The time series I’m modelling in the end being an acoustic one.